# Filtering object based on object values

Tags: powershell, object

Comparing VLANs in my VMware environment to the VLANs in my UCS environment. I first read all the VLANs available in VMware into `$vCenterVLANList`, which returns an object looking like this:

```
Portgroup VLANID
--------  ---
MgmtVLAN  5
ProdVLAN  10
QVLAN     15
```

(real list of course much longer)

Then in my UCS system I want to search by VLAN ID for all VLANs with this ID. A VLAN ID can exist multiple times but under different name:

```
Name         ID
--------     ---
MgmtVLAN     5
ProdVLANDC1  10
ProdVLANDC2  10
QVLAN        15
TESTVLAN     20
```

The above list is obtained using `Get-UCSCentralVLANs`.

What I would normaly do now is create a `foreach` loop on `$vCenterVLANList` and then for each portgroup, search the VLAN ID in `Get-UCSCentralVLANs` and create a new object to which I parse portgroup, VLANID and the UCSCentral VLAN Name.

Trying to learn to write some better PowerShell and so I was hoping this can also be done in a one liner that would result in:

```
Portgroup VLANID UCSVLAN
--------  ---    -----
MgmtVLAN  5      MgmtVLAN
ProdVLAN  10     ProdVLANDC1
ProdVLAN  10     ProdVLANDC2
QVLAN     15     QVLAN
```

So I then would be building a `foreach` loop like:

```
$MatchedVLANs = @()
foreach ($VLAN in $vCenterVLANList) {
    $UCSVLANs = Get-UCSCentralVLANs | Where-Object( $_.ID -eq $VLAN.ID)
    foreach ($FoundVLAN in $UCSVLANs) {
        $row = "" | select Name, ID, UCSName
        $row.Name = $VLAN.Name
        $row.ID = $VLAN.ID
        $row.UCSName = $FoundVLAN.Name
        $MatchedVLANs += $row
    }
}
```

Comment: It's been said before but "one-liners" aren't "better". In my opinion, "better" code is robust and readable. Using on-liners undermines both of these :)

Comment: Ah I see, I thought it would be more efficient because of fewer calls.

Comment: Could you update your question with what you are currently using? :) If you are calling the `Get-UCSCentralVLANS` command in each of your loops then that would be inefficient.